# Architecture & Libraries To Use Feedback

Tags: python, node.js, backend

I'm a frontend developer, fairly new to backend. I have a project I'm working on and would like feedback on how to best architect it and what libraries to use so I dont build something that ends up not working.

My knowledge: Javascript (front end). Have been learning NodeJS and a small amount of python. Would like to build in nodeJS since thats my main experience.

My project: I have a database with about 200 rows. I have 5 computers. I want each computer to be given a row from the database, perform a function (varies how long it takes between 2-10minutes), then move on to another row which is available.

(The reason for the 5 computers is each task needs to have a unique location. The computers are in different locations and on a different network)

Solution I'm thinking of doing: 1 of the computers is the main server. It will send the row # to each of the other 4 computers. It will wait to recieve a message from the assigned computer telling it the task was completed. Then it will assign it the next row on the list. ie:

Server to Computer 1: do row 1
Server to Computer 2: do row 2
Server to Computer 3: do row 3
Server to Computer 4: do row 4
Computer 2 to Server: "done".
Server to computer 2: do row 5
Computer 4 to Server: "done".
Server to computer 4: do row 6
Computer 1 to Server: "done".
Server to computer 1: do row 7

etc

My questions:

- Is this the best way to architect this or is there a better way?
- How do I connect all the clients to the server since they're on different networks?
- What libraries do I need to accomplish all this?

Comment: Sounds like a question regarding distributed computing architecture. This isn't the right SE for it, but I think you can ask it on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) ? 
StackOverflow is for [specific problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: More specifically, asking for libraries is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll move it to Programmers.